# 26 letters probability: how many combinations do you have to make?

Tags: education

How to calculate soccer result with propability

Comment: this seems more like a problem than an open data question...can you clarify how this relates?

Answer (score 1):

26C9(without repetition) would be the answer.

The method described here:- ([combinations](http://www.intmath.com/counting-probability/4-combinations.php)) 
is used to find out how many combinations are possible.

As for listing them down, they would be a little bit too many to list down with a pen and paper I guess. You could, however, use tools like [the combination generator](http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/combination-permutation-tools/combination-generator/)